# Maintenance Plan Fails But Query Runs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, backup, database-backups, maintenance-plan

I have an SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition whose Maintenance plan fails constantly with the error:

```
backup MYSERVER (MYSERVER)
Backup Database on MYSERVER
Databases that have a compatibility level of 70 (SQL Server version 7.0) will be skipped.
Databases: All databases
Type: Differential
Append existing
Task start: 2011-10-18T00:10:09.
Task end: 2011-10-18T00:10:09.
Failed:(-1073548784) Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE [model] TO  DISK = N'\\myNetworkDrive\\opovo\\BackupSQL\\MYSERVER\\model\\model_backup_201110180010.bkp' WITH  DIFFERENTIAL ,  RETAINDAYS = 13, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'model_backup_20111018001008', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
" failed with the following error: "Cannot open backup device 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL.1\\MSSQL\\Backup\\Arca\\opovo\\BackupSQL\\MYSERVER\\model\\model_backup_201110180010.bkp'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

But the query:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [model] TO  DISK = N'\\myNetworkDrive\\opovo\\BackupSQL\\MYSERVER\\model\\model_backup_201110180010.bkp' WITH  DIFFERENTIAL ,  RETAINDAYS = 13, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'model_backup_20111018001008', SKIP, REWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

runs normally and gives me the expected results.

Is this a bug?
What am I missing here?
What is the elegant way to backup to a network location?

Comment: even stranger is the error message: "Cannot open backup device 'C:\\Program Files(...)" maybe there's a difference between how SSIS and SSMS/SS Agent handles the backslash?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the account that SQL Server Agent service runs as.  If the account doesn't have permissions on that network share, then it won't be able to see that path.  Executing that query outside of a SQL Server Agent job (indirectly through a maintenance plan) doesn't use the security context of the SQL Server Agent service.

Make the SQL Server Agent service run as a domain account with access to that network share.

Comment: I tried to run the query with the same user and to create a job with the query and then run it. Both worked, but the maintenance plan, which uses SSIS, doesn't.

Comment: @LynxKepler I'm talking about the SQL Server Agent service account.  Configure it to run under the context of a domain account through the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: at the services.msc console I saw the "SQL Server Agent" service, on the last column (Log On As) it says it's running under "MyDomain\ABC.MyUser"; with this same user I could access the network share, invoke the job and run the query successfully.